# Retrofit POST request sending email field with %40 instead of @

Tags: retrofit

I am trying to figure out a way to stop Retrofit from encoding the email address that I pass to make a POST request. Here is my POST interface

```
@POST("/security/oauth/token")
@FormUrlEncoded
void getAccessToken(@Field("client_id") String clientId,
                  @Field("client_secret") String clientSecret,
                  @Field("username") String username,
                  @Field("password") String password,
                  @Field("grant_type") String grantType, Callback<AccessToken> cb);
```

When I make the request, Retrofit sends these fields as

```
client_id=test&client_secret=cajcckkcaaa&username=androidtest12%40gmail.com&password=Password23&grant_type=password
```

The culprit here is the email address, which is being changed from androidtest12@gmail.com to androidtest12%40gmail.com causing server error.

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set `encodeValue = false` for your username field for this to work because it is being encoded. They have this documented over at the [Retrofit Javadoc](http://square.github.io/retrofit/javadoc/retrofit/http/Field.html#encodeValue--). An example is below using your data.

```
@POST("/security/oauth/token")
@FormUrlEncoded
void getAccessToken(@Field("client_id") String clientId,
              @Field("client_secret") String clientSecret,
              @Field(encodeValue = false, value = "username") String username,
              @Field("password") String password,
              @Field("grant_type") String grantType, Callback<AccessToken> cb);
```

Comment: I tried this in kotlin and it didn't work for me. @Field(value = REQUEST_USERNAME, encoded = true) username: String

Answer (score 5):

For [Retrofit 2](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) you should use `@Query` with `encoded = true` like this:

```
public interface ValidateEmailApi {
    @GET("/api/email")
    Call<Void> validateEmail(@Query(encoded = true, value = "email") @NonNull String email);
}
```

Comment: what if I want it in @Field